# Como criar nomes de variáveis durante a execução de um código?

Tags: python

Preciso de uma pequena ajuda.

Durante a execução de um código eu obtenho uma lista com x entradas (o tamanho da lista varia de acordo com o input). Cada entrada dessa lista é um array linha com um certo numero de elementos, não necessariamente iguais entre si.

Para facilitar o acesso durante o resto do código, eu gostaria de nomear cada entrada dessa lista como uma variável no seguinte esquema:

```
lista[0] = cD_x

lista[1] = cA_x

lista[2] = cA_(x-1)

lista[3] = cA_(x-2)

...

lista[x] = cA_1
```

Como x varia a cada execução não tenho ideia de como fazer isso.
Alguem pode me dar uma ajuda, por favor?

Comment: Tem como explicar por quê acessar uma variável criada dinamicamente será melhor que acessar o índice de uma lista?

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa necessariamente identificar os arrays, e provavelmente nem deva fazê-lo, já que são dinâmicos. Veja o exemplo:

```
tudo = [];

# Adicionando listas sem identificador em "tudo"
tudo.append([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
tudo.append(['banana', 'laranja', 'manga'])
tudo.append([0.456, 2.56, 0.0000004, 0.223, 33.33333])
tudo.append([True, True, False, True, False, False])

# A menos que você queira explicitamente identificar algo
# Aqui um lista tem o nome "especial"
especial = [4, 'Moscou', 32, 'Severino Raimundo', 0.5]
tudo.append(especial)

# E agora eis uma das formas de percorrer tudo o que existe
for lista in tudo:
    print()
    for elemento in lista:
        print(str(elemento))

# Podemos nos referir as listas por índice também
# Nesse caso você tem um "i" e um "j" nos quais "se agarrar"
for i in range(len(tudo)):
    print()
    print('LISTA ' + str(i) + ':')
    for j in range(len(tudo[i])):
        print('index[' + str(j) + '] = ' + str(tudo[i][j]))
```

---

Reescrita do segundo laço de acordo com a sugestão do Anderson Carlos Woss:

```
# Podemos nos referir as listas por índice também
# Nesse caso você tem um "i" e um "j" nos quais "se agarrar"
for i, lista in enumerate(tudo):
    print()
    print('LISTA ' + str(i) + ':')
    for j, elemento in enumerate(lista):
        print('index[' + str(j) + '] = ' + str(elemento))
```

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Editei a resposta inserindo sua sugestão.